# Touchable opacity not working when clicked on the sides

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

Touchable opacity is not working when clicked on the edges of the button. It only works when clicked the centre of the button. Why is this behaviour happening?

#### Code

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection:'row',marginTop:20,alignSelf:'center',alignItems:'center',justifyContent: 'center',width:'80%',height:60,backgroundColor:'#140F79',borderRadius:20}}>
    <Icon name="plus" size={15} color="white"   />
    <Text style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat-Bold',margin:10,fontSize:20,color:'white'}} onPress={()=>showAstro(itemdeets)}>Add to Cart</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be handling `onPress` on `TouchableOpacity` instead of `Text`. It was detecting presses only on `Text`.

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection:'row',marginTop:20,alignSelf:'center',alignItems:'center',justifyContent: 'center',width:'80%',height:60,backgroundColor:'#140F79',borderRadius:20}} onPress={()=>showAstro(itemdeets)}>
    <Icon name="plus" size={15} color="white"/>
    <Text style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat-Bold',margin:10,fontSize:20,color:'white'}}>Add to Cart</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```